# Redux - Adding/removing items from normalised state tree

Tags: redux, react-redux

I've just normalised the state of an app I'm working on (based on [this article](https://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/reducers/NormalizingStateShape.html)) and I'm stuck trying to add/remove items from part of my state tree based on quantity.

Part of my state tree `cart` is solely responsible for housing the quantity of tickets that are in the cart, organised by ID. When the user changes the quantity, an action is dispatched `UPDATE_QTY` which has the `qty` and the `id`.

The state starts off correct as the incoming data has the `qty` but I can't seem to figure out the syntax to remove the item from the `cart` reducer if `qty` is `0`, also how to add it back in if the `qty` is 1 or more.

Could someone offer advice on the correct syntax to achieve this please?

**EDIT:** I'm wondering if I'm trying to do too much inside the `UPDATE_QTY` action and that I should have separate actions for deleting and adding items.

**byId reducer**

```
export function byId(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case SET_INITIAL_CART_DATA:
      return Object.assign({}, state, action.tickets);

    case UPDATE_QTY: // Here, I need to check if action.qty is 0 and if it is I need to remove the item but also add it back in if action.qty > 0
      return {
        ...state,
        [action.id]: { ...state[action.id], qty: action.qty }, // Updating the qty here works fine
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

**Simplfied state tree**

```
const state = {
  cart: {
    byId: {
      '40': { // How can I remove these items when qty is 0 or add back in if > 0?
        qty: 0,
        id: '40'
      },
      '90': {
        qty: 0,
        id: '90'
      }
    },
    allIds: [
      [
        '40',
        '90',
      ]
    ]
  },
}
```

I also need the IDs to be reflected in my `allIds` reducer.

**allIds reducer**

```
export function allIds(state = [], action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case SET_INITIAL_CART_DATA:
      return [...state, ...action.allIds];

    case UPDATE_QTY:
        return [ONLY IDS WITH QTY]
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

For this I'm not sure if the `allIds` reducer needs to be connected to the `byIds` reducer and take information from there. I would love to hear what best practice for something like this would be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why have separate reducers for `byIds` and `allIds`? I would combine these into one `cart` reducer and maintain the `allIds` state with `byIds`:

```
case SET_INITIAL_CART_DATA:
  // just guessing here...
  const { tickets } = action;
  const allIds = tickets
    .reduce((arr, ticket) => arr.concat(ticket.id), []);

  return {
    byIds: { ...tickets },
    allIds
  }

case UPDATE_QTY: {
  const { byIds, allIds } = state;
  const { id, qty } = action;
  const idx = allIds.indexOf(id);
  const next = { };

  if (qty > 0) {
    next.byIds = {
      ...byIds,
      [id]: { id, qty }
    };
    next.allIds = idx === -1 ? allIds.concat(id) : [ ...allIds ];
    return next;
  }

  next.byIds = { ...byIds };
  delete next.byIds[id];

  next.allIds = idx === -1 ? [ ...allIds ] : [
    ...allIds.slice(0, idx),
    ...allIds.slice(idx + 1)
  ];

  return next;
}
```

However, what state do you want normalized? If this represents a shopping cart of tickets, the tickets are what would be normalized, and the cart would just represent the quantity of tickets to be purchased. Then your state would look something like this:

```
{
  tickets: {
    byIds: {
      '1': { id, name, price, ... },
      '2': { ... },
      '3': { ... },
      ...
    }
    allIds: [ '1', '2', '3', ... ]
  },
  cart: [
    { id: 2, qty: 2 },
    { id: 1, qty: 1 }
  ]
}
```

The use of an array for the cart state maintains insertion order.

Comment: Jeepers! I thought I had responded to this. Please accept my apologies on the delay of response. Your suggestion worked perfectly. I think you're correct in saying that I should normalise the tickets and then use an array for the cart. I had tried this but couldn't get the order of insertion working properly. Will for sure use this next time I work on a shopping cart!

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes *(when you only iterate through ids and get by id)* it's enough to remove id from allIds and skip all unnecessary computations.

```
    case actionTypes.DELETE_ITEM: {
        const filteredIds = state.allIds.filter(id => id !== action.itemId);
        return {
            ...state,
            allIds: filteredIds
        };
    }
```